# VB.NET - Clicking button fast won't work because other code needs to execute

Tags: vb.net

I made a button which has a animation to it when you click it. It won't do the animation everytime when you click fast and you don't get points for everyclick then either.

It's hard to explain but I'll try!
Here's an image of the button and the label displaying the points:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDViq.png

When I click the button fast 10 times, it goes down and up again around 3-5 times. Same for the points! You don't get another point until the button is up again. I could just remove the animation but that would look ugly!

Here's the code for the button:

```
Private Sub PictureBox7_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox7.Click

        My.Settings.amount += 1
        Dod()
    End Sub

    Public Sub Dod()

        amount.Text = My.Settings.amount.ToString

        amount.Location = New Point((Width - amount.Width) / 2, amount.Location.Y)

        PictureBox7.BackgroundImage = My.Resources.clicked_0
        Timer1.Start()

    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        'My.Settings.amount += 1
        Timer1.Stop()
        PictureBox7.BackgroundImage = My.Resources.ICO256
    End Sub
```

The timer interval is set to 50. The best thing would be if I was able to make the button animate as fast as you click...

Comment: whats the purpose of the timer?

Comment: @Plutonix I bet it's for a delay.  Set the image, then set it back.  My guess.

Comment: Making the button go up after 50ms. Maybe it would work to instead animate it when you release the mouse?

Comment: the resolution of the timer is not so fine tuned for that...there is a note on MSDN (which I am sure you read) where a 55 or 60ms lower threshold is mentioned.

Comment: When you click fast then you generate DoubleClick instead.  An event that you did not subscribe.

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you! What's left now is to animate the button correctly.

Comment: Anyone know how I would do that? So that the button have one image when it's clicked and another when it's released?

Comment: Oh wait, I feel stupid now. Mouse Down and then Mouse Up...

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it very easily by doing the event for click in MouseDown instead and instead of a timer with a delay, I simply made the button go up on MouseUp!

That way, the button will go up when I release the mouse. That's what I want :)